# How can I split csv file into separate files with header row and 1 line of data

Tags: csv, awk

How can I split csv file into files with header row and 1 line of data.  I was planning on using AWK, but any alternatives of course gratefully received.  I want to split a csv file into single row files (with header row).  For example, I want to take something like this:-

```
FirstName, Age, Sex
John,45,Male
Paul,24,Male
Mark,87,Male
Sue,29,Female
```

And produce four files that look like this:-

File 1:

```
FirstName, Age, Sex
John,45,Male
```

File 2:

```
FirstName, Age, Sex
Paul,24,Male
```

etc....

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{h=$0;next}{f="file"++i;print h,$0 > f;close(f)}' OFS='\n' file
```

Example:

```
$ ls
file

$ cat file
FirstName, Age, Sex
John,45,Male
Paul,24,Male
Mark,87,Male
Sue,29,Female

$ awk 'NR==1{h=$0;next}{f="file"++i;print h,$0 > f;close(f)}' OFS='\n' file

$ ls
file  file1 file2 file3 file4

$ cat file1
FirstName, Age, Sex
John,45,Male

$ cat file2
FirstName, Age, Sex
Paul,24,Male

$ # ect
```